# How do I setup jQuery Datatables in a Parent/Child relationship?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatables

I currently have to 2 `asp:GridView` that are linked in a Parent Child relationship.  I find the GridView control hideous and would like to replace it with the jQuery-Datatable but cannot seem to figure out how to set them up.

I realize I need to change them to HTML `<tables>` but other then that what?  For other implementations of Datatable I have used a `Generic Handler` for returning the data as `json`.  Would I simply do the same thing and tie them together through the jQuery row click event?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready( function ()
    {
        $( '#tags' ).dataTable( {
            "ajax": 'GetTagsHandler.ashx',
            "columns": [
                { "title": "Tag Description" ,
                  "data": "name"}
            ]
        } );
    } );
</script>
```

and an example of my Handler for the above example:

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        HttpRequest request = context.Request;
        HttpResponse response = context.Response;

        response.Write("{ \"data\": [");
        bool writeDelimiter = false;

        using (SqlCommand cmd = DBUtils.GetNewCommandObject())
        {
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT crmTags.TagID, crmTags.Name FROM crmTags WHERE crmTags.InstanceID=@InstanceID";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InstanceID", Instance.CurrentInstanceID);

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                if (!writeDelimiter)
                {
                    writeDelimiter = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    response.Write(",");
                }

                response.Write(string.Format("{{\"DT_RowId\":\"{0}\", \"name\":\"{1}\"}}", dr["TagID"].ToString(), dr["Name"].ToString()));
            }
            dr.Close();

        }
        response.Write("]}");
    }
```

Comment: what's the behavior you are looking for? Not sure if child would need ajax to populate or all data delivered to master. Not sure if you are looking for sub rows or separate tables

Comment: Sorry, When you click on a row in the one table there is a FK that I use to grab, potentially hundreds of, rows for the second table.  Kind of like `Customer/Orders` type setup.

Comment: not sure what a FK is. Not hard to get row reference data in click handler to pass to ajax request and either destroy existing child datatable instance and reinitialize with new data, or just dump existing data using API and pass in new data. API is extremely flexible so not sure where your exact problems lie